# Update an existing war on jboss EAP 7 without redeploy

Tags: deployment, jboss

On my Jboss EAP 7 server an application.war is deployed. Now i want to update and add some class and jsp files.How can i update existing war without deploying whole war?

Comment: You could explode your deployment and add content to it using jboss-cli https://wildfly.org/news/2017/09/08/Exploded-deployments/

Comment: Are you using EAP 7 or 7.1?

Comment: @Abhijeet EAP7.1

Comment: @ehsavoie can we use zip to update a large number of files?

Comment: Yes you can deploy a war then explode it. But afterwards it is file per file. You can also explode jars in the same way if you want to update a class in a lib

Comment: @ehsavoie there are more than 15 files and it is not easy to update file per file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ehsavoie as per your suggestion I can change only jsp file but for Web-Content files I need to  restart the application and here is the catch that Jboss maintain the checksum of every deployed application but you copy your new file at an already exploded application. This doesn't affect checksum so, now after restart it explodes your last .war and your changes reverted.
Efficient way to partial deployment is use deployment:add-content command in cli mode.

/deployment=DEPLOYMENT_NAME.war:add-content(content=[{target-path=/path/to/FILE_IN_DEPLOYMENT, input-stream-index=/path/to/LOCAL_FILE_TO_UPLOAD}]

Here is the [link](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.1/html/configuration_guide/deploying_applications) if you want to read more.

Comment: You really came back after 1 year and 5 months, That is incredible.

Comment: @Tuqay  I have already implemented this long before. Hope this answer help others.